# Get Item custom column values from document set using Rest API in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I need to get the custom column values of items in document set through REST API. I wrote the below API:

```
https://SiteURL/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='SIteurl/Library/DocumentsetName')?$expand=Folders,Files,ListItemAllFields
```

Above API is giving defalut column values. I need to get the Item Id and other custom values.

Need help on this.

Thanks,

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use graph api, please refer to following endpoint

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields
```